# bootstrap datepicker - beforeShowDay is not firing, I want to highlight dates on calender

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

```
 $('#txtDate').datepicker({
        format : 'mm/dd/yyyy',
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            alert("firing beforeShowDay");
            var Highlight = SelectedDates[date];
            if (Highlight) {
                return [true, "Highlighted", Highlight];
            }
            else {
                return [true, '', ''];
            }
        }
    });
```

beforeShowDay is not firing when I load bootstrap datepicker, Please give me solution.

Comment: Bootstrap does not have a datepicker.  `beforeShowDay` belongs to [Jquery UI](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay).  Be aware that Jquery UI and Bootstrap have some compatibility issues that must be addressed to work together.

Comment: Also, make sure `#txtDate` has `type="text"`